# How do I install vim-gnome on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.10, vim

On one laptop running Ubuntu 19.04 I have installed vim-gnome without any problems. On a second laptop running Ubuntu 19.10 I get the following error when using:

`sudo apt install vim-gnome`

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package vim-gnome is not available, but is
>   referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
>   missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'vim-gnome' has no installation candidate

How can I install vim-gnome on a laptop running Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: `vim-gnome` has not been packaged for later than 19.04, refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vim-gnome.  I don't see the immediate cause (Qt4 is being removed; GTK2 is being removed causing other like packages to be removed) but I I don't follow it's development (ie. GTK3 changes may have require changes that haven't been performed but that's guess only).

Comment: I believe the package you are looking for is `vim-gtk3`.

Comment: +1 to @Terrance comment, the https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/eoan/vim confirms this idea, so write your idea as answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`vim-gnome` has been removed from the repositories for 19.10.  However, the `gtk3` version is available and is pretty much the same package.

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, vim-gtk3 has the system clipboard support which is what I was looking for. Thanks.